# Tkinter Buttons and Multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Off Button Not working in python. I have a code in python in which I'm trying to get the off button to turn a function off while the function on is running. as on runs it prints out hello every 5 seconds and I want the off button to stop this. Every time I press the off button it freezes while hello is still being played or python crashes. How can I fix this?.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading

root = Tk()

def on():
    threading.Timer(5.0, on).start()
    print("hello")

def off():
    exit()
    
buttonstart = Button(root, text="on", command=on)
button = Button(root, text="off", command=off)
buttonstart.pack()
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's unclear why there is so much repeated code in your question — was that intentional? If not, please [edit] your question and fix it. That said, generally speaking, `tkinter` doesn't support multithreading.

Comment: This code doesn't use threads, it starts a timer, while `off` tries to exit the application instead of stopping the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cancel()` to cancel the `Timer()`:

```py
timer_task = None

def on():
    global timer_task
    buttonstart.config(state=DISABLED)
    timer_task = threading.Timer(5.0, on)
    timer_task.start()
    print('hello')

def off():
    global timer_task
    if timer_task:
        timer_task.cancel()
        buttonstart.config(state=NORMAL)
        timer_task = None
```